# Django user does not inherit permission from group

Tags: python, django, authentication

Consider the following output of a Django shell session:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
>>> g=Group.objects.all()
>>> g
<QuerySet [<Group: Tester>, <Group: Testmanager>]>
>>> g[1].permissions.all()
<QuerySet [..., <Permission: testman | test plan step | Can add test plan step>, <Permis
sion: testman | test plan step | Can change test plan step>, <Permission: testman | test plan step |
 Can delete test plan step>, <Permission: testman | test plan step | Can view test plan step>, ...]>
>>> g[1].user_set.all()
<QuerySet [<User: somedude>, <User: testma>]>
>>> u=User.objects.all()
>>> u
<QuerySet [<User: somedude>, <User: test>, <User: testma>]>
>>> u[0].has_perm('testman.create_testplanstep')
True
>>> u[2].has_perm('testman.create_testplanstep')
False
```

I have defined two groups, Tester and Testmanager. User somedude is a site admin and also a member of group Testmanager. User testma ist not a site admin but also in Testmanager. Group Testmanager has all permissions on the model TestPlanStep. Yet the user testma does not get the permission. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: user testma is active.

Edit2:

```
>>> u[2].username
'testma'
```

Comment: Is user `testma` active?

Comment: can you check that `u[2].username` is "testma", just to be sure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to be sure that permission names are correctly constructed:

```python
g = Group.objects.all()
perms = g[1].permissions.all()
us = g[1].user_set.filter(is_active=True)
missingperms = set()
for u in us:
    for p in perms:
        pstring = p.content_type.app_label + '.' + p.codename
        if not u.has_perm(pstring):
            missingperms.add(pstring)
print('missing permissions count:', len(missingperms))
```

The output should be 0 missing permissions.

Addendum:
The fact that a superuser has a specific permission is no proof that the permission is a valid one. You can try this for instance:

```
u = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)[0]
u.has_perm('burn_down_the_house')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The permission that gets added to the model automatically is called "create_..." but the permission that you add in the admin site is called "add_...". So

```
>>> u[2].has_perm('testman.add_testplanstep')
True
```

Strange, though. Doesn't make sense to me to have different names for those.