# Django Permission

Tags: django, django-permissions

Hi i am having trouble with Django User object.

I have created a group named 'Admin' and this group have the following permission 'can_change_name','can_update_name'.

A user 'falcon' belong to group 'Admin' i did this by performing the following query

```
user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='Admin))
```

When i perform the following query i am getting False instead of True.

```
user.has_perm('can_change_name')
```

The above query give me False, i have a doubt why i am getting False even after adding the user into the appropriate group.

Comment: Permissions are for a specific model, not general. It needs to be something like "my_model:can_change_name".

Comment: You very likely got the permission name wrong. To check for the exact name you need to use, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441985/django-user-does-not-inherit-permission-from-group/54447175#answer-54447175).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes you are right that one works for me